# Create custom helper for PopUp in asp.net MVC3.0 with aspx viewEngine

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net MVC 3.0 with aspx View engine, Now I need to prepare a popup helper in mvc in which data is passed in form of dt and other attributes as parameters(like css,text...) The popUp should appear on click of a button and I need to combine the functionality of button and popup in single helper,
That means in Html.customHelper I need a button whose click event should show the popup and all parameters related to button and popup should be passed in the respective helper(html.control).

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be useful to what you want to do:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: This is creating a simple label but I need to know how to get the click event of button(in the helper) and show a div with the data and an exit button. In this link i can't see any event being fired.